# acer aspire 4736g shut down unexpectedly

Tags: shutdown, acer-aspire

My laptop currently has some weird issues. My laptop shuts down without bluescreen. It happened randomly. I don't think it should

Be overheating problem because I've just applied new thermal paste and keep an eye on the core temperature.

The randomly shut down occurs more during starting up the laptop. It normally shuts down few time before I reach the logon screen. However,  It stills shuts down when I'm in normal use like surfing the web, downloading, or even when I did nothing.

> Windows event viewer log shows kernal-power, 41(63).

Besides, there's issue where my laptop can't power up using battery now. The battery still working when I start up using adapter and then take off the adapter. I'm not sure whether this two issues are related.

Answer (score 0):

Check this KB article about the Kernel 0x41 Event:

**[Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first" in Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504)**

Look if you get a bugcheck, in this case share the dmp files, if bugcheck is 0x0, check all 5 steps from scenario 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's a motherboard problem with the Acer 4736G laptops. A lot of these problems have been reported. Sometimes it works just fine for hours, and sometimes shuts down five times in 10 minutes.

You need to repair your motherboard, it'll cost you around 200$ for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably not the battery but a badly implemented Acer design feature. On the reverse side, there are a series of Torx screws. If the hardware detects any are open, it kills power as a "safety" feature. This is done to reduce the risk of a fire should the user open the case and turn on power to the laptop. This sounds nice, but the feature has been implemented poorly because the screws are self-loosing over time! Try tightening the screws hard. A Torx screwdriver (with changeable heads) can be picked up from a good hardware store for a few dollars.

The problem (with resolution) is [described in great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1008809/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-running-on-battery).