# Toshiba Laptop suddenly shuts down when on battery

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, power

I'd be grateful if someone coud help me.
My Toshiba L845 laptop suddenly shuts down when on low battery. It doesn't hibernate in the usual way it did. It completly powers off, as if someone had pulled off the power chord of a desktop PC. It's not a battery issue since it's a new battery, and the same problem happened with my old battery.
Some time ago the power jack was loose and I took it to a technical support store to reapair it. Maybe they messed up some other thing and that's why it is malfunctioning now? I don't know. Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be relevant, but a similar problem plagues Acer laptops. There is a safety feature which kills power when the hardware detects the case is open (and power is on). By tightening some screws on the reverse of the laptop, the problem magically goes away. The screws are self-loosing so this may need to be repeated every few years.

The problem (with resolution) is [described in great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1008809/laptop-shuts-down-suddenly-when-running-on-battery).